# How to disable the option of hidden parameter extraction

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Web performance test is detecting dynamic parameter and then adding extraction rule ...how to avoid this issue I want to disable the option of auto correlation in visual studio and want to manually co relate the dynamic values

Comment: be more descriptive :)...